# Setting gcc ( gcc-arm-embedded ) in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Mars in OS X

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, toolchain

I am a newbie in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ .
I want to set gcc-arm-embedded in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Mars Milestone 4 (4.5.0M4), I just downloaded https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download, and now I guess that I have to set PATH somewhere in Eclipse, as I am experiencing this ERRORs in 1 project

```
Program "arm-none-eabi-g++" not found in PATH
Program "arm-none-eabi-gcc" not found in PATH
```

The location of the error is in 
Project Properties -> C / C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc -> Languages (GNU C) -> [ CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM]

But I can't edit this entry: "Setting entries for this provider are supplied by the system and are not editable"

I've tried with:

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/joanot/Development/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin

and in

Project Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> adding the directory /Users/joanot/Development/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin
and

Comment: Is it windows or linux? Set the environment path variable, it will do the trick.

Comment: ok, not familiar with OSX, but I believe there is an environment variable to be set as well.

Comment: but inside Eclipse or outside ?

Comment: Outside. At least in Linux and Windows.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: I've tried with no exit, I see the compiler from outside, but have the same Error in Eclipe

Comment: Which path are you setting?

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/Users/joanot/Development/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin

Comment: edit: Sorry, disregard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In    `Eclipse -> Preferences -> C / C++ -> Build -> Build Variables:`

Create 1 variable named GCC_EABI, type= Directory, value= /usr/local/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4/bin

In    `Eclipse -> Preferences -> C / C++ -> Build -> Environment:`

Add -> Name = PATH , value = ${GCC_EABI}

Comment: I also added the build tools path to GCC_EABI, otherwise it complained "make not found".  On my machine:  GCC_EABI = C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q2-update\bin;C:\Program Files\GNU MCU Eclipse\Build Tools\2.9-20170629-1013\bin\bin

Comment: great advice Lode! Ugh I have bad memory, and do I love this platform!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone reads this later (like I just did) this works, however the real answer is [here](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/support/faq/)

Essentially you need to go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> C/C++ Build -> Tools Paths
Add the path (in my case /Users/${USER}/armtools/install/bin) to the Toolchain folder